# Finding the limit of the DF of the arithmetic mean of RVs

Tags: probability, integration, normal-distribution

Suppose we have $$S_n = \frac{X_1 + X_2 + ... + X_n}{n}$$
where all the $X_i$ ~ $N(0,1)$.

Then I am asked to find the CDF of $S_n$, and also find the limit of $S_n$ as $n$ approaches infinity.

Now the way I found the CDF was to find out what distribution $S_n$ was, which is easily found as:

$S_n$ ~ $N(0,\frac{1}{n})$. Then it is easily computed from this.

What I am struggling with is the limit factor. If $n$ approaches infinity,  $S_n$ ~ $N(0,0)$, which makes no sense. But the textbook says that the limit of $S_n$ is also in fact a CDF. Maybe I have to use the integral definition of the CDF and take the limit of an integral(but that's another problem in itself). I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong, or if there's something I'm missing. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: By DF, you mean distribution function?

Comment: Yes, I may edit to CDF just to clarify.

Comment: The CDF of $S_n$ is $F_S(x) = \Phi(\sqrt{n}x)$, where $\Phi$ is the CDF of standard normal. So it should converge to the Heaviside step function pointwise. We can see that for the continuous part of this limiting function is identical to a degenerate distribution at $0$, so we say $S_n$ converge in distribution to that.

Comment: how did you discern that $\Phi((\sqrt n)x)$ is the CDF?

Comment: Also note that $\Phi$ does NOT equal 1 as x goes to infinity, found easily through the gaussian integral.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is correct that $S_n\sim\mathcal{N}(0,\frac{1}{n})$, but its exact meaning is that as $n\to\infty$, the pdf (which is a Gaussian function) becomes more condensed at zero. Let's assume $X=S_n$ for simplicity. We need to have $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_{X}(x)dx=1$$
Hence, we should have $f_{X}(0)\to\infty$ as well.

It follows that $$\lim_{n\to\infty} f_X(x)=\delta(x)$$
So the arithmetic mean of $n$ standard normal variables tends to zero with probability one as $n\to \infty$.